# Create tables with entities - Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entities

I created several classes without using the php command `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity`, directly I created and mapping  the php classes in the folder `MyBundle/Entity`.

What is the command to generate these classes as Doctrine entities and Mysql tables?

Comment: You can use `php app/console doctrine:database:create` to create the database and then `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. You can read more in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Comment: When execute php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force a error appear: No Metadata Classes to process.

Comment: You are mapping your your classes using annotations?  Make sure you don't have any orm files hanging around under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: @Cerad Yes I had a file in Resources/config/doctrine, when I deleted it I could generate the tables! Thank you very much

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have all the needed annotations and correct getters / setters in your php files, it should be enough to call `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. For preview purposes ypu can use `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`. That will show you the sql which will be executed.

If you only have annotated properties without getters / setters (so you have created the php files, added properties which you want as columns and added their respective annotations), first use `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle/Entity`. This will create the getters/setters for you. Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters) for additional information.

Comment: When execute php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force and php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql appear a error No Metadata Classes to process

When execute p
hp app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acc\ApssBundle\Entity
appears [RuntimeException]
  Namespace "Acc\ApssBundle\Entity" does not contain any mapped entities.

Comment: That happened to me several times. Check that your namespace definition is correct according to the php file path. Check that you have added `@ORM\Entity` annotation above the entity class definition. Finally check if you're having the correct path in the `doctrine:generate:entities` command. Note that you also have to include the folder above the bundle in the path, afaik (example: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities App\MainBundle\Entity`).

Comment: I checked this, I program with eclipse symfony plugin and I see a error in doctrine-mapping.xsd ':cos-nonambig: WC[##other:"http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"] and WC[##other:"http://doctrine-
 project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During 
 validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.'   Ahy idea?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for your entities, especially the code with the doctrine entity annotations? I don't know if I'll be able to help, but someone surely will. Also, please paste the exact symfony command you're trying to execute.

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Mohar I solved with the Cerad comment

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use migration mechanism.  There is great tool for the Symfony ([DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html))

1. Create an entity class with all necessary properties;
2. Create getters / setters( using IDE or app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle:Entity);
3. Create migration file(app/console doctrin:migration:diff);
4. Use the migration(app/console docttrin:migration:migrate);